# Custom user model doesn't create objects

Tags: python, django

I have created a `CustomUser` model and it has a one to relationship with my two other models.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_learner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    #teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Learner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

They do not show up when I try to create learner and teacher objects in their respective databases, as shown:

```
class LearnerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()


    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        #User = CustomUser
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
        #fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_learner = True
        user.save()
        learner = Learner.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

How do I get it to save in learner and teacher tables respectively?

Comment: This design is almost certainly suboptimal. The denormalization / redundancy of the teacher / learner flag is unnecessary and hard to maintain.

Comment: Please can you show the `UserCreationForm` as you are inheriting from this class

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

It is worth pointing that using `model.objects.create(...)` you're implicitly telling Django that you want to create the object with the specific values you give and save it. [check the docs page here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create)

If you wish to save an object for which has associated items, you can create a form and use a `ModelChoiceField` and provide the model and default choices using the `choices` kwarg. An example of a choices value would be `YourUserModel.objects.all()` However, I think in your case you may not want to give the user the freedome to make this choice, in which it would be correct to override the `save()` method of your form and create the intended logic.

Secondly, I have used Django for quite some time and never seen a `Model.Meta` class used in this way so forgive me if I'm mistaken, but I also think you need have your `save()` method directly on your `LearnerSignupForm` and not on the `Meta` class.

Thirdly, if you setup your forms correctly, using the correct types of fields, Django forms will deal with all the messy stuff for you and complain at you when you do something wrong (usually gracefully).

Lastly, I would highly recommend having a read through the [docs page for creating new objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields)

Free code:

```
class LearnerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_learner = True
        # create the relationship between the user and learner
        learner = user.learner_set.create(user=user)
        # user.learner_set.add(learner) # usually this way with FK
        user.save()
        return user # should this return the Learner object?
```

One final bit of advice:

Try to make your code as readable as possible! There's no reason that code can't be functional and beautiful! And where possible, you should make you class names and variable names as appropriate as possible, I would for example maybe use `Student` instead of `Learner`

Comment: Sorry, I approved your edit suggestion, but didn't noticed it has an error. `class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):` should go inside `class LearnerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):`, could you please re-edit the question?. And `def save...` at the same level of class Meta.

Comment: @slackmart hey bud. I thought that as well, but he seems to be doing something strange with the inheritance of that class, and it seems to be standalone from the form class itself. **EDIT** nevermind, he is inheriting  the original form Meta and it should be tabbed accordingly

Comment: Yes, it seems weird at the beginning, but syntax is valid. `class Meta` is inheriting `UserCreationForm.Meta`.

Comment: It was the initial tabulation that threw me!